# Remove row and create new array

Tags: perl

I am reading a CSV file

```
A B C D
A 1, 2, 3, 4
B 5, 1, 7, 8
C 9, 4, 1, 2
D 2, 7, 8, 1
```

The idea is to compute matrix correlation

How can I remove a row and create a new array?

I tried this

```
my @new_row = split(/\s+/, $header_line);
```

This is my first Perl program

```
my @row = /@desired_row/ && $_;
```

#### current output

```
A 1,2,3,4
```

#### What I am trying now

```
my @newarray = ( );
@newarray = grep ($_ > 2, @row);
print "@newarray\n";
```

#### Result I am trying to get

```
A 3, 4
```

Comment: What is your input.?

Comment: I am actually reading csv file   A  B C D
                                              A 1, 2, 3, 4
                                              B 5, 1, 7, 8
                                              C 9, 4, 1, 2
                                              D 2, 7, 8, 1  . The idea is to compute  matrix correlation

Comment: `@newarray = grep ($_ > 2 || $_=~m/[a-z]/i, @row);` Just try I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Please read about [ask] good questions, and then [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. My interpretation is that you are trying to read a correlation matrix into a Perl data structure. The fact the matrix has unit diagonal seems to support that interpretation. On the other hand, the matrix is not symmetric, so that's even more confusing.

I am assuming you are confused about how to remove the variable labels, and just getting the numbers into a matrix. In Perl, you can represent a matrix either as an array of references to anonymous arrays (dense matrix) or as a hash whose keys are row or column indexes and values are references to anonymous arrays (sparse matrix). The choice of whether to store column vectors or row vectors can affect how well you can work with the data, but, once again, there is not enough information in your question to deduce what would be most appropriate in your situation.

The code below shows the most basic way of reading that matrix into a Perl data structure. In your code, you would `open` the data file and assign a filehandle, e.g. `$fh`, and read from that rather than the `__DATA__` section of your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @vars = split ' ', <DATA>;
my @correl;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    push @correl, [ $line =~ /([0-9]+)/g ];
}

print join("\t", @vars), "\n";
print join("\t", @$_), "\n" for @correl;

__DATA__
A B C D
A 1, 2, 3, 4
B 5, 1, 7, 8
C 9, 4, 1, 2
D 2, 7, 8, 1
```

Output:

```
A  B   C   D
1   2   3   4
5   1   7   8
9   4   1   2
2   7   8   1
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up fixing, This is my first time writing Perl so it was kind of tough to understand the syntax and all. Thank you tho